# Как в Django осуществлять перебор двумерного списка в шаблоне?

Tags: django, список, вывод, django-template

В Django я новичок, и не очень получается такая штука:
Имеется двумерный список уже в шаблоне

```
[{'street': 1L, 'house': 1L, 'customers__sum': 12}, 
 {'street': 1L, 'house': 2L, 'customers__sum': 2}, 
 {'street': 2L, 'house': 1L, 'customers__sum': 32},
 {'street': 2L, 'house': 2L, 'customers__sum': 5},
 {'street': 2L, 'house': 3L, 'customers__sum': 2},
 {'street': 3L, 'house': 1L, 'customers__sum': 7}]
```

Как в шаблоне последовательно вывести сначала дома улицы один, потом дома улицы 2 потом дома улицы 3 (и суммы к ним соответственно)?

Comment: может не django может  python?

Comment: Та не. Тут именно в Django, так как интересует манипуляция непосредственно в шаблоне.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup)

Comment: Супер. 
А теперь чуть усложняется.
Параллельно есть еще один список с аналогичными ключами
Список ордеров от каждого дома:

[{'street': 1L, 'house': 1L, 'orders__sum': 2}, 
 {'street': 1L, 'house': 2L, 'orders__sum': 2}, 
 {'street': 2L, 'house': 1L, 'orders__sum': 3}]

Можно ли по этим ключам сгруппировать 2 списка (в один)

Comment: По двум ключам "в лоб" - нет. Вообще, обработку данных должны делать модели, в крайнем случае -  view, но уж точно не шаблон. Нужно подготовить данные, а потом уже готовый сгруппированный список передать в шаблон.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, для начала, это не двумерный список, а список словарей(хешей) :)
Обойти его можно так:

```
{% for dict in my_list %}
    Улица: {{ dict.street }}, Дом: {{ dict.house }}
    Клиенты: {{ dict.customers__sum }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Да. Это очевидно. Но тут речь идет скорее о представлении домов в разрезе улиц. Т.е. С начала к примеру берется Улица№1 и выводятся все дома и абоненты, потом Улица№2 и её дома и абоненты, ..... Пока есть улицы, а у улиц дома ...